# Splitting a string into substrings so that each string starts with a capital letter?

Tags: r, string, split

I have the following string:

dt <- "I feel the night explode When we're together Emotion overload In the heat of pleasure Take me I'm yours into your arms Never let me go Tonight I really need to know Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name The passion's so complete It's never ending As long as I receive This message you're sending Body to body, soul to soul Always feel you near So say the words I long to hear Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name Love...love on the run Breaking us down Though we keep holding on I don't want to lose No...I can't let you go... Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name Tell it to my heart Tell me from the stars Tell it to my heart Tell it to my heart Tell me from the stars Tell it to my heart Never make it stop Oh take it to the heart Oh no no ah ah Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name"

I tried 
 unlist(strsplit(dt, split = "[[:upper:]]"))

but it takes out the capital letters.

I want to split it so that each string starts with a capital letter. For example,
  "I feel the night explode",
  "When we're together",
"Emotion overload", etc.

Is there a way to split it like that? Thanks!

Comment: Likely the sexiest question ever asked on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of "lookarounds"

```
x <- "I feel the night explode When we're together Emotion overload In the heat of pleasure Take me I'm yours into your arms Never let me go Tonight I really need to know Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name The passion's so complete It's never ending As long as I receive This message you're sending Body to body, soul to soul Always feel you near So say the words I long to hear Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name Love...love on the run Breaking us down Though we keep holding on I don't want to lose No...I can't let you go... Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name Tell it to my heart Tell me from the stars Tell it to my heart Tell it to my heart Tell me from the stars Tell it to my heart Never make it stop Oh take it to the heart Oh no no ah ah Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name"
v <- unlist(strsplit(x, split = "(?=\\s[A-Z])", perl=TRUE))
v <- v[v!=" "]

head(v)
# [1] "I feel the night explode" "When we're together"     
# [3] "Emotion overload"         "In the heat of pleasure" 
# [5] "Take me"                  "I'm yours into your arms"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ooh_yeah_baby_baby <- "I feel the night explode When we're together Emotion overload In the heat of pleasure Take me I'm yours into your arms Never let me go Tonight I really need to know Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name The passion's so complete It's never ending As long as I receive This message you're sending Body to body, soul to soul Always feel you near So say the words I long to hear Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name Love...love on the run Breaking us down Though we keep holding on I don't want to lose No...I can't let you go... Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name Tell it to my heart Tell me from the stars Tell it to my heart Tell it to my heart Tell me from the stars Tell it to my heart Never make it stop Oh take it to the heart Oh no no ah ah Tell it to my heart Tell me I'm the only one Is this really love or just a game Tell it to my heart I can feel my body rock Every time you call my name"

unlist(stringr::str_split(ooh_yeah_baby_baby, "(?=\\p{Upper})"))[-1]
```